# MetadataExtractor - Public member 'OfType' on type 'List(Of Directory)' not found

Tags: .net, vb.net, metadata-extractor

This code

```vb
Dim vImageFlag As Integer = 0
If System.IO.File.Exists(Row("Image")) Then
    vImageFlag = 1
    Dim vDirectories = MetadataExtractor.ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(Row("Image"))
    Dim vSub = vDirectories.OfType(Of MetadataExtractor.Formats.Exif.ExifIfd0Directory)().FirstOrDefault
    If Not vSub Is Nothing Then
        Dim vOrientationObj = vSub.GetObject(MetadataExtractor.Formats.Exif.ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation)
        If Not vOrientationObj Is Nothing Then
            If Not vOrientationObj.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                vOrientationNumber = Convert.ToInt16(vOrientationObj)
                vOrientationFlag = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If

    For Each vDirectory In vDirectories
        vEXIF += vDirectory.Name & vbCr
        For Each vTag In vDirectory.Tags
            vEXIF += vbTab & " " & vTag.Name & " " & vTag.Description & vbCr
            IsEXIF = 1
        Next
    Next

End If
```

works fine on some pages but blows out with others at

```
Dim vSub = vDirectories.OfType(Of MetadataExtractor.Formats.Exif.ExifIfd0Directory)().FirstOrDefault
```

At all times there is an image at the path
[image: Debug]

Really stumped on this one - but it's probably staring me in the face :-)

Thank you

[image: Error point]

Stacktrace

```
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers  (String& MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
at HOAManagerClient051.MultiViolations_Page._Closure$__13-0._Lambda$__4() in C:\Path\HOAManagerClient051\HOAManagerClient051\Pages\Board\Violations\MultiViolations_Page.xaml.vb:line 822
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? It's not clear what you mean by 'blows out'. Is there an exception? If so, what does it say?

Comment: System.MissingMemberException
  HResult=0x80131512
  Message=Public member 'OfType' on type 'List(Of Directory)' not found.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic

Comment: `OfType` is an extension method provided by `System.Linq`. I'm surprised you get that exception if your code compiled correctly. Are you targetting multiple frameworks? I think there must be something special going on with your environment.

Comment: Targeting 4.6 only. The only difference between it working and not working is the path string comes from a TextBox where it works and a Grid where it doesn't. Baffles the brown stuff out of me!

Comment: That is very strange. I wonder if the missing member exception is coming from the debugger (VS), as method binding occurs via the JIT before any code runs. Can you wrap the code in a try/catch and log out any caught exception?

Comment: Added stacktrace to question

Comment: Looks like it's using some kind of VB late binding. What if you use `Enumerable.OfType<...>(...)` instead of the extension method form?

Comment: Argument not specified for parameter 'source' of 'Public Shared Overloads Function OfType(Of ExifIf0Directory)(source As IEnumerable) As IEnumerable(Of ExifIfd0Directory)'